# Recording audio on Mac

Tags: cocoa, macos, audio

I am developing an application which access my audio input device and record audio from my microphone.
Here when i am pressing START button it have to record audio from microphone and have to stop recording when pressing STOP button.

My device is Lynx-AES16 and i got driver from there site.

In windows i am accessing the machine(Lynx) by using direct-show SDK(Graph edit). 
Is there any similar tool  like direct-show is available. I checked with AUAudio and IOkit but didnt understood that much.

Can anyone provide some sample or some useful links. Apple link is not good for a starter

Comment: What does this have to do with the iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the CoreAudio sample code at [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com). There is plenty of useful code there.

In particular look at the [RecordAudioToFile](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/RecordAudioToFile/Introduction/Intro.html) example.

Comment: i went much on developer.apple.com. As a starter its little difficult to understand the things there.

Comment: I suggest you start with the RecordAudioToFile sample code - compile that and run it, study the code, make changes, etc - you'll learn a lot that way.

Comment: ok thanku sir...
Can u give me the link for htat sample program

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/samplecode/RecordAudioToFile/index.html 
this is the link right